# Beginner JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript

It's my first time using Java Script....

What does this do?

```
var INTEGER_SINGLE = /\d+/;
```

What does the forward slashes tell you? How about the backslash? `d` means for digit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That creates a regular expression that matches one or more digits.

Anything inside `/ /`  is a regular expression.  `\d` matches a digit, and `+` is the positive closure, which means one or more.

---

Having said that, depending on what this regex is supposed to do, you may want to change it to:

```
var INTEGER_SINGLE = /^\d+$/;
```

`^` matches the beginning of the string, and $ the end.  The end result would be that any strings you try to match against the regex would have to satisfy it in the string's entirety.

```
var INTEGER_SINGLE = /^\d+$/;

console.log(INTEGER_SINGLE.test(12));    //true
console.log(INTEGER_SINGLE.test(12.5));  //false
```

---

Of course if the regex is supposed to only match a **single integer** anywhere in the string, then of course it's perfect just the way it is.

Comment: The name INTEGER_SINGLE suggests it will match single integers anywhere in a string. The suggested `/^\d+$/` would more properly be named "ONLY_DIGITS" or similar as it matches strings that consists of only digits. Of course without more context, anything is reasonable.

Comment: @Rob - I was trying to figure out what that variable name meant; now I feel silly for thinking so hard after your comment -- thanks -- edited

Comment: @AdamRackis - thanks so much. Now I know at least to learn about regular expression. Without you help I don't even know where to start looking at...

Comment: @RobG - thanks for the additional comment. Sorry i never used JavaScript before and did not know to put more context. Your help is very much appreciated :)